# how to get single variable name from struct

Tags: swift, mirror

I have a core data framework to handle everything you can do with `coredata` to make it more cooperateable with codable protocol. Only thing i have left is to update the data. I store and fetch data by mirroring the models i send as a param in their functions. Hence i need the variable names in the models if i wish to only update 1 specific value in the model that i request.

```
public func updateObject(entityKey: Entities, primKey: String, newInformation: [String: Any]) {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityKey.rawValue)
        do {
            request.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "\(entityKey.getPrimaryKey())==%@", primKey)
            let fetchedResult = try delegate.context.fetch(request)
            print(fetchedResult)
            guard let results = fetchedResult as? [NSManagedObject],
                results.count > 0 else {
                    return
            }

            let key = newInformation.keys.first!
            results[0].setValue(newInformation[key],
                                forKey: key)
            try delegate.context.save()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

As you can see the `newInformation` param contains the key and new value for the value that should be updated. However, i dont want to pass `("first": "newValue")` i want to pass `spots.first : "newValue"`

So if i have a struct like this:

```
struct spots {
    let first: String
    let second: Int
}
```

How do i only get 1 name from this?

i've tried:

```
extension Int {

    var name: String {
        return String.init(describing: self)
        let mirror = Mirror.init(reflecting: self)
        return mirror.children.first!.label!
    }
}
```

I wan to be able to say something similar to:

```
spots.first.name
```

But can't figure out how

Comment: Didn't understand the problem statement. Kindly clarify.

Comment: What do you mean by `get 1 name from this`?

Comment: Your desires are probably wrong. :) Any time you find yourself wanting to introspect like this, you are doing something unSwifty. You should explain to us what the real problem is, that makes you _think_ you need to do this.

Comment: By using mirror i can just loop through the children and print the `children.label` to get the names, but i want 1 specific name

Comment: Ok, a deeper explination is coming give me a second

Comment: @matt its updated now

Comment: I think you have not fully understood the power of Core Data and how well it integrates with your model objects since such a framework should not be needed. So instead of re-inventing KVC you should directly work with your NSManagedObject subclasses to get and set properties.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I understand it, however it's oudated. The NSManagedObject is not cooperating with Codable and therefor i need to create a solution which does the same but actually cooperate with Codable

Comment: And what output do you expect after `spots.first.name` ?

Comment: @Kirow "first" is what i expect. The name of the variable called

Comment: *The NSManagedObject is not cooperating with Codable*. That's wrong. Indeed `NSManagedObject` **is** able to cooperate with `Codable`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I understood question, but...what about this?

```swift
class Spots: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var first: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var second: Int = 0
}

let object = Spots()

let dictionary: [String: Any] = [
    #keyPath(Spots.first): "qwerty",
    #keyPath(Spots.second): 123,
]

dictionary.forEach { key, value in
    object.setValue(value, forKeyPath: key)
}

print(object.first)
print(object.second)
```

or you can try swift keypath:

```swift
struct Spots {
    var first: String = ""
    var second: Int = 0
}

var spots = Spots()

let second = \Spots.second
let first = \Spots.first

spots[keyPath: first] = "qwerty"
spots[keyPath: second] = 123

print(spots)
```

however there will be complex (or impossible) problem to solve if you will use dictionary:

```swift
let dictionary: [AnyKeyPath: Any] = [
    first: "qwerty",
    second: 123
]
```

you will need to cast `AnyKeyPath` back to `WritableKeyPath<Root, Value>` and this seems pretty complex (if possible at all).

```swift
for path in dictionary.keys {
    print(type(of: path).rootType)
    print(type(of: path).valueType)
    if let writableKeyPath = path as? WritableKeyPath<Root, Value>, let value = value as? Value { //no idea how to cast this for all cases
        spots[keyPath: writableKeyPath] = value
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a great attempt, and i looked at it myself, however, i it's still bound as a `keyPath`, which limits me, as i need it as a `string`. Or maybe i just didn't get it working like you explained?

Comment: @Vollan actually `#keyPath(Spots.first)` will return you a String "first". But you need to make it `class` inherited from `NSObject` and set all properties as `@objc dynamic var`

Comment: yeah, that way i know of, but i don't want to use it like that :/ sorry and thanks